# Some strings disappear in DT when using filters with searchHighlight option

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, dt

There is an issue connected with **DT** filtering when using individual column filters + the **searchHighlight** option.

*Steps to reproduce:*

1. Use this code to generate a simple **DT** table with a single character column:

```r
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(
  test_chr = paste0('test', 1:10)
)

datatable(
  df,
  filter = "top",
  options = list(
    searchHighlight = TRUE
  )
)
```

[image: изображение]

2. Type `test1` in **tst_chr** individual column filter;
   [image: изображение]
3. Cancel search by erasing search query or by clicking the clear button;
4. The word `test` disappears in nearly all rows.
   [image: изображение]

Comment: Are you just trying to publicize https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/813? Do you know if this is a bug in the underlying `DataTables` javascript package? A similar-sounding issue was raised in the forum in 2015, https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29253, not sure if it's related (if so, then it's likely in DataTables itself, and unlikely to be resolved?

Comment: @r2evans I don't think it is a bug because I found this solution in the documentation of datatables.

Comment: Funny ... I can't think of a time when I would _want_ or expect that behavior ... but that's just me. Glad there's a clear workaround for that "feature".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. Use this `callback` and this works:

```r
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(
  test_chr = paste0('test', 1:10)
)

datatable(
  df,
  filter = "top",
  options = list(
    searchHighlight = TRUE
  ),
  callback = JS(
    "table.on( 'draw', function() {
        var body = $( table.table().body() );
        body.unhighlight();
        body.highlight( table.search() );  
    } );
    "
  )
)
```